# How to add China region option in Chrome to GitLab's phone number verification when registering?

Tags: gitlab, google-chrome-devtools

When registering a new user with GitLab, there is no China region option for phone number verification. How to add China region option (+86) using DevTools in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Just to be sure, you know [JiHu Gitlab](https://gitlab.cn/en/) exists?

**Disclaimer: I have no idea if this works, as I only have a US phone number, and it depends on Gitlabs method of sending texts. It is worth a try, though.**

**1. Right click over the "Country or region" that is selected, as shown here:**
[image]

On the right side, you will see this element:

```
<span class="gl-new-dropdown-button-text">
         Taiwan (+886)
      </span>
```

and you can double click on  `Taiwan (+886)` to edit it. Change this to `CH China (+86)` and click enter. That should change the selection to display China

**2. Right click over the Country Code (+1 in my case) and click Inspect, as shown here:**

[image]

This will open up the Chrome dev tools on the side, highlighted over the desired element that you want to change. Notice it is currently highlighting the line with `<div class="input-group-text"> +1 </div>`; that is the line you want to change.

Simply double click on the "+1" and change it to "+86". Click enter on your keyboard. This will change the leading number to 86 instead of 1, and look like this:

[image]

I was able to change it from "+1" to "1" in dev tools and it still worked for me, so I have a feeling theres a chance this could work. Let me know your results.

EDIT 2:
if the above does not work, it looks like Gitlab sometimes requires a phone number, and sometimes doesn't, based on [this forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/unable-to-create-account-without-cellphone-number/89930/3). It uses Arkose which detects risks to the platform; this "risk" score determines if a phone number is required. If you are in China, you'll likely be flagged because it seems normal Gitlab is unavailable in China; if you are on VPN, you are probably on a more "risky" IP according to Arkose. Your best bet would probably be getting an account made with your email from a less risky IP/device outside of China, if possible.

Comment: Doesn't work: "There was a problem with the phone number you entered. Enter a different phone number and try again." Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no China region option for phone number verification in GitLab, than that country code is not supported for phone number verification.

Manipulating the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) or trying to forge the API request via chrome devtools will not work since this capibility does not exist for a reason. The reason could be due to a technical limitation, the actual phone number verification system not supporting that country ([example](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/guidelines/cn/sms)), or a specific policy in that country.

This [blog post from GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/08/04/gitlab-support-no-longer-processing-mfa-resets-for-free-users/) mentions a [thread that discusses limitations around some countries with phone number verification and two factor authentication](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/54401).

That being said, [GitLab has other verification options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/identity_verification.html#email-verification) including email, so you may not need to verify your phone number. I suggest reaching out to [GitLab support](https://about.gitlab.com/support/) for further guidance.

Comment: However both email and phone number verification are required. As one comment says in the [thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/54401) you gave: _It's impossible to say it's not supported, Google account can be verified by phone in China._

Comment: @Blackteahamburger have you been able to try my answer above? Curious if it worked